# Can't identify pedals or find cleats

Tags: pedals, clipless

These pedals were on a used bike I purchased a year ago or so. I just switched them out for some old pedals I had because I didn't have cleats or shoes. Now I want to buy cleats and shoes, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what these pedals are. Can anyone identify these and point me in the right direction for getting some cleats?[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFrt0.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, probably SPD-R.  You'd probably be better off buying new pedals that are compatible with modern shoes.

Comment: You could cut a piece of thick plastic to go in the cleat hole on each pedal, and then ride them as normal flats, with flat shoes.   I've temporarily fitted old cleats so I could ride the road bike more comfortably with flat shoes, and not have to carry shoes to the destination.   You might get some money back by flogging these on Ebay, retro riders might be interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are SPD-R pedals. SPD-R is Shimano's older road pedal system, and its cleats have different bolt pattern than either SPD or any other road pedal. The cleats are still available from some online shops, but you need either old SPD-R compatible shoes or an adapter plate to use them.